# eclipse Description: Type internal_static_callRequest_descriptor cannot be resolved or is not a field callRequest.java Java Problem

Tags: eclipse, protocol-buffers, grpc, distributed-system, grpc-java

I am building up a gRPC project (study purpose only) on eclipse, but my java files aren't being generated as their should be.

Below I will describe all the step that I did to start the project:

1. First of all, created the project and named the package (groupId) and the class (artifactID).
2. I copied and pasted all the necessaries dependencies on my pom file
3. I created my proto files.
4. I run the proto files and I got the error "Type internal_static_callRequest_descriptor cannot be resolved or is not a field"

The java files were created, but with a compile error.

No idea what I am suppose to do as I cannot edit the generated files.

I am brand new on gRPC, trying to learn it now. Then, any help or advice will be awesome

Thanks a million =)

Comment: Where did you copy the dependencies from? Can you give the full error message (the file name failing to build, with any context it provides)? Did you create the proto files, or were they copied from somewhere?

Comment: for me this error was caused when I added a message, generated, then deleted the message, then generated again (without clearing the destination folder), this resulted in some leftover files from the previous generation which caused the issue.